# github cli multiple accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-cli

I am trying to use [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

So far I am able to use it to list out PRs in our company's repo.

The issue is when I try to checkout a PR via `gh pr checkout 123` where `123` is the PR number.

When I do so I get this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit status 128
```

The error shows because it's trying to use `git@github.com`. But I don't use `git@github.com` because I have multiple accounts on GitHub. So I have set up my `.ssh/config` to be:

```
Host github.com-companyA
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/companyA

Host github.com-companyB
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/companyB
```

I think the solution is to modify `git@github.com` to `git@github.com-companyA:foo/bar.git`

But I don't know where I can modify it using GitHub CLI.

My ultimate goal here is to checkout a PR, run some tests on my local machine, then label the PR for either passing or failing.

I can work on the projects using git with no issues. I can push and pull just fine. It's just that I want to automate checking out the branch of the PRs on GitHub. I have no control over what my team names their branches.

PS
The companies I am working on are using different technologies, and that both companies have multiple PRs a day.
I just want a way of testing multiple PRs automatically so that I don't have to do them one by one.
Both companies are also using `GitHub Actions`.

Comment: I know this. And this is not what I am after. My git config for each project works perfectly. It's just that `gh pr checkout` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Dec. 2023: [GitHub CLI gh v2.40.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.40.0) does include... **Multiple Account Support**!

It reflects the "[Multi-account support on GitHub.com](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-03-multi-account-support-on-github-com/)" announced in Nov. 2023.
See "[Switching between accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/switching-between-accounts)".

Regarding `gh`:

> Thanks to [Gabe Cook (`@gabe565`)](https://github.com/gabe565) for his efforts to support multi-account capabilities with [`gh-profile` extension](https://github.com/gabe565/gh-profile) for this [long requested feature -- issue 326](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/326)! ❤️
>
> This release focuses on several specific use cases:
>
> - adding multiple accounts for GitHub.com and GitHub Enterprise with `gh auth login`
> - switching manually between accounts for `gh` and `git` use with `gh auth switch`
> - seeing multiple accounts with `gh auth status`
> - logging out of accounts with `gh auth logout`
>
> Future enhancements such as automatic account switching based on context and more automatic Git configuration will be planned based on community feedback.
>
> For much more detail about the specific of multiple account support in this release as well as a discussion of the sharp edges, please see this doc.
>
> Please provide feedback in our [release discussion](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/8429).

So you now (Dec. 2023) have:

```bash
                               GitHub CLI (gh v2.40.0)
                                       │
          ┌────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┐
          │                                                          │
          ▼                                                          ▼
    gh auth login (CompanyA)                               gh auth login (CompanyB)
    gh auth switch --account CompanyA                      gh auth switch --account CompanyB
    gh pr checkout, gh issue/pr commands                gh pr checkout, gh issue/pr commands
          │                                                          │
          └────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┘
                                       │
                              GitHub.com Repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

`gh pr list` has a flag:

`-R, --repo [HOST/]OWNER/REPO   Select another repository using the [HOST/]OWNER/REPO format`

This would then list all PRs along with the branch names.
I can then use `grep` to get the branch names.